# Loading a bmp file to a picturebox

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

I am using a `picturebox` to display a `bmp` image when a  `wav` file is playing. My problem is that I cannot access image file when my application is used by other computers.My code is stated below:

```
        string chosen_File = "nowplaying.bmp";
        string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(chosen_File);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: your application is used by other computers ?

Comment: Have you provided them the images `directory`? Or is the every image has individual directory ?

Comment: Check if the image is present in the computers from where you are trying to access the application

Comment: Are all the applications using the same image file from a share or something similar? If so, read the file and close all references to the file, dispose of all related streams.

Comment: @zey -  it is save to other directory.

Comment: @Shaharyar - i saved the image in bin folder of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Package the Image with your program and make the `chosen_File` refer to the

`Application.StartUpPath + "\\your.jpg";`

Comment: what do you mean by "package the image with your program".Sorry I am new to programming.

Comment: @hana Google how do I `deploy/release/package` a winform application. If you go the MSI route then you simply include the image in the package.